# Finding with matrices

Tags: matrices

just practicing for my advanced Hong Kong diploma and I've found some matrices problems I'd like to look at. Usually quite comfortable with these but have found some I'm not so sure on. In terms of what they are asking.

I have some matrices $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 &0\\  
                       4 &−6\end{pmatrix}, \qquad B = \binom 1{-1} $$

I need to find 
1) $3A$
2) Half of $A$
3) $2B$

For number one do I just multiply it by itself?
For number two would I simply half the given matrix entries?
For number 3 Do I literally just multiply it by itself also?

So for example for number two I'd have 
$$ \frac 12 A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0\\  
                       2 &−3\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: You are right. Multiplying a matrix by scalars amounts to multiplying each element of the matrix by the scalar.

Answer (score 3):

For any matrix 
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}\\
\end{array}\right)$$
and any $c\in\mathbb{R}$, the matrix $c\cdot{A}$ is defined as
$$c\cdot A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
c\cdot a_{11} & \cdots & c\cdot a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
c\cdot a_{n1} & \cdots & c\cdot a_{nn}\\
\end{array}\right).$$
With the above you can solve all your questions. But I guess this can be found at Wikipedia as well `:)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is so helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, this and much more can also be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))

Answer (score 2):

You are right, we have: 
$$ 3A = \begin{pmatrix} 6 &0\\  
                       12 &−18\end{pmatrix}, 
\quad \frac 12 A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0\\  
                       2 &−3\end{pmatrix}, \quad 2B = \binom{2}{-2} $$

Comment: Thank you for confirming for me, that's really helpful.